# Access Private NPM modules on AWS Node Container

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, npm

On my local machine I have a .npmrc file which contains the appropriate credentials token to access my private modules. When I deploy an application via EBS to a Node container it, of course, does not have access to that file and fails to find the private modules.

I tried just including the .npmrc file into the application bundle but that didn't work.

Can anyone guide me into how to set this up?

Answer (score 1):

Ok the following worked for me.

1. create .ebextensions dir in root of bundle
2. Add a file 01_npm.config to that dir

File contents:

```
files:
  "/tmp/.npmrc":
    content: |
      //registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken=xxxx
```